# Prove that there exists $ \theta $ such that $ |f\left(x\right)-f\left(y\right)|\leq|f'\left(\theta\right)||x-y| $

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^2} $ a differentiable function.

How can I prove that there exists $ \theta \in [x,y] $ such that $ |f\left(x\right)-f\left(y\right)|\leq|f'\left(\theta\right)||x-y| $ for any $ x,y $ ?

Here's what I tried:

First note $ f\left(x\right)=\left(f_{1}\left(x\right),f_{2}\left(x\right)\right) $

Next,

$ |f\left(x\right)-f\left(y\right)|=|\left(f_{1}\left(x\right)-f_{1}\left(y\right),f_{2}\left(x\right)-f_{2}\left(y\right)\right)|\underset{Lagrange's\thinspace\thinspace Theorem}{=}|\left(f_{1}'\left(\theta_{1}\right)\left(x-y\right),f_{2}'\left(\theta_{2}\right)\left(x-y\right)\right)|=\sqrt{\left(f_{1}'\left(\theta_{1}\right)\right)^{2}+\left(f_{2}'\left(\theta_{2}\right)\right)^{2}}|x-y| $

If I knew that $ f_1 $ and $ f_2 $ accept the maximum value at the same point, that would solve the problem, but Lagrange's theorem only promise me $ \theta_i $ between $ |x-y| $ for each $ f_i $ and it does not has to be the same $ \theta $. How can I overcome this problem and find a better bound?

Comment: Hint: Cauchy-Schwarz :)

Comment: @zugzug I actually asked it in order to get an idea to prove for $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C} $. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint:

Cauchy-Schwarz inequality says that $|a\cdot b|\leq \|a\|\|b\|.$

Consider the function $g:[x,y]\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(\theta)=(f(x)-f(y))\cdot f(\theta)$.

Comment: Im sorry I cant see where this leads me, would you please elaborate?

Comment: The idea of the problem is to apply the mean value theorem to a real-valued function. Then apply Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: to apply the mean value theorem to $ g $ ? between which points?